# Bind to scroll and watch the argument - better way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I wanted to create a simpler version of jQuery Waypoints.js (sticky elements on the page) in AngularJS. I created a special directive to watch the scroll and it looks like this:

```
app.directive('watchScroll',function($window){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            var win = $window;

            angular.element(win).bind('scroll',function(){
                scope.watchScroll = win.pageYOffset;
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    }
})
```

And then on any DIV I want to 'waypoint', I add the following directive:

```
app.directive('animateThis',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
            scope.$watch('watchScroll',function(s){                         
                if(s >= 100){ // do stuff here } else { // do the opposite stuff here }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

This works fine, but I just wanted to know if this is a good approach and if not, what would you change?

Comment: This seems as good approach as any. It's clean and separated, what more would you want?

Comment: Just double checking really. I don't want to end up with a slow working app that is binding a variable to scroll and then watching that variable change from several different elements. But I guess this is the logical way every other library would work.